# How do I keep my Android app running in the background all the time

Tags: android

I want to know how to keep my Android app running in the background 24/7 for correctly timed notifications.

Comment: Why do you think that you need to be "running in the background 24/7", and that it will have any impact on your ability to have "correct timed notifications"?

Comment: You need to take a piece of paper and write down what your goal is. Having an app running 24/7 is not a good idea. Better to figure out what your goal is and choose an appropriate strategy to accomplish it.

Comment: If you want correctly timed notifications, perhaps look at push messages like something along the lines of GCM (google cloud messaging).

Comment: @JoxTraex I agree, but it's probably better to use [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) over GCM. From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/), "Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) is the new version of GCM. It inherits the reliable and scalable GCM infrastructure, plus new features!... If you are integrating messaging in a new app, start with FCM. GCM users are strongly recommended to upgrade to FCM, in order to benefit from new FCM features today and in the future."

Comment: @EJoshuaS that is why is said "something along the lines of" :) wasn't sure what other cloud like messages would be available but thanks for providing the latest standard!

Comment: @JoxTraex I thought so, just wanted to point that out :)

Answer (score 1):

for correctly timed notifications you either use Push Notifications or the AlarmManager.

Active waiting should be avoided on mobile handsets, because it will drain battery...

If you have to do something in background you use a Service or a IntentService.

Comment: I agree with this, especially with the idea of using Push Notifications for this: [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/)

Answer (score 0):

Basically Android mobile devices are not designed for 24/7 run, but :

For avoid the device enter deep sleep you can use PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK but your app will drain a lot of battery.

To prevent the system from killing your application you should launch a Service and call startForeground from it.

Comment: With Doze mode, app standby, and the new O restrictions on background work, none of this will have an app run continuously.

Answer (score 0):

You can run app in background by implementing

**Service** [ to run app in the background, without UI interface ]

+

**AlarmManager** or **WakeLock** [ to check repeatedly if your app is working, since Android might kill process for memory ]

You can follow these for service implementation

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_services.htm

AlarmManager can be implemented with

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

However your purpose of running app in background is only to display notifications, you could schedule them with AlarmManager alone.

Answer (score 0):

As other people have indicated, 24/7 active waiting is neither desirable nor necessary.

For one thing, as noted in other answers, this drains the battery.

For another thing, you simply can't count on 24/7 availability for cell phones for your app to work correctly - there's too much that can go wrong (battery goes dead, the user turns the phone off, etc.).

I strongly recommend that you use [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) (push notifications) instead; this can reliably and inexpensively deliver messages to phones in a power-efficient manner.